# Como posso criar uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Eu preciso criar uma lista, onde a mesma listará todos os itens existente dentro de um pedido.

No método abaixo eu consigo trazer um item, porém não consigo trazer caso tenha mais de um.
A minha dúvida seria, tenho que criar um método no `code behind`  e na `classe` não sei como funciona a lógica de listas.

Código(observar a linha [itemPedido]):

```
protected void ExibirProtocoloPedido(PedidoVenda objPed)
{
    try
    {
       PedidoVendaItens objItPed = new PedidoVendaItens();
       Produtos objProd = new Produtos();

    Session["pedEmpresa"] = objPed.PedEmpresa;
    Session["numPedido"] = objPed.PedNumero;
    Session["msgOfertas"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgOfertas.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgOfertas.ToString() : "");            
    Session["itemPedido"] = objItPed.ItPProduto + " - " + objProd.ProdDescr + "/" + "Qtde.:" + objItPed.ItPQtde  + " / " + "Total:" + objItPed.ItPrecoComp;
    Session["msgMatApoio"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgMatApoio.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgMatApoio.ToString() : "");
    Session["msgReorderGerado"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderGerado.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderGerado.ToString() : "");
    Session["msgReorderAtendido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderAtendido.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderAtendido.ToString() : "");
    Session["msgReorderNaoAtendido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderNaoAtendido.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderNaoAtendido.ToString() : "");
    Session["msgPendencias"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgPendencias.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgPendencias.ToString() : "");
    Session["valorPedido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValACobrar.Text) ? string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", txtValACobrar.Text) : "0");
    Session["statusPed"] = objPed.PedStatus;
    Session["formaPagto"] = objPed.PedForPgto;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", "ShowProtocolo();", true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
    }
}
```

O resultado que me retorna desse método é:

> 2210 - Devione 125ML / Qtde.: 1 / Total: 15,75

Comment: A primeira coisa que você deve fazer neste código é tirar o `try-catch`, está fazendo nada. Na verdade está fazendo algo, prejudicando o *stack trace*, mas nada útil. Não entendi o que deseja saber. Que listas? Tem muitas. Que lógica? O que quer fazer?

Comment: @bigown Seria listar item a item, separando por linha...
Como eu mencionei na pergunta, esse metódo lista um item. AGora quando tem mais de um item, ele só traz o primeiro item, então queria saber como pode ser criado um tipo de lista
para criar quantidade de linhas de acordo com a quantidade de itens no pedido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisar criar um objeto do tipo List PedidoVendaItens

Assim:

```
List<PedidoVendaItens> objLista = new List<PedidoVendaItens>();
```

Depois usar o método Add para adicionar os itens à lista.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, o que entendi pela pergunta é que precisa colocar uma lista de produtos dentro da sessão. é isso?
Se for, você não consegue colocar a lista como um objeto. Vai precisar serializar a sua lista.
Se for este o caso, recomendo o newtonsoft.

Caso não seja esta a pergunta, pode me esclarecer um pouco mais?